# A simple interpretation of algebraic cycles as homology classes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, intersection-theory, algebraic-cycles

I understand an algebraic cycle to be a formal linear combination of closed irreducible subvarieties of some variety $X$ (over $\mathbb{C}$).
I guess to make things concrete, make $X$ smooth and projective with dimension $n$.

Now I have read that a $\operatorname{codim} p$-cycle $Z$ in $X$ defines a $(2n-2p)$-dimensional homology class $[Z] \in H_{2n-2p}(X)$.
My question is

> What/is there a pedestrian explanation of why this is the case, and how to visualise it?

Even an example with say $\mathbb{P}^1$ would be helpful here.
I know very little algebraic geometry overall (say only Hartshorne I and the first few chapters of II), so hopefully a minimal amount of reference to say divisors or intersection theory would be ideal (but I'm not sure if this is possible!)

Comment: I think the easiest interpretation is not from algebraic geometry but differential geometry (remember: the point of most “easy” cohomology theories is that they measure supposedly different things but still end up equal anyway). $H_{2n-2p}(X)$ can be seen (in some way) as a space dual to $H^{2n-2p}(X)$ which is a space of differential forms. So a closed subvariety $Z$ is associated with the linear map $\omega \longmapsto \int_Z \omega$.

Comment: this is more of a philosophical statement: any good cohomology theory should have this property. the motivation is that in complex geometry by Poincare duality you can construct the map $H^\star(Z)\to H^\star(X)$ and if $Z$ has dimension $d$ , there is the trace map $H^2d(Z) \to k$ which is an isomorphism. combining this two map give you the cycle map on any cohomology theory that satisfy pioncare duality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question:** "What/is there a pedestrian explanation of why this is the case, and how to visualise it?"

**Answer:** After 19.1.1 in Fulton "Intersection theory" they define the cycle map $cl: A_*(X) \rightarrow H_*(X)$ for any "Borel-Moore homology theory" $H_*$. The group $H_{2n}(X)$ contains the fundamental class $cl(X_i):=[X_i]$ for all its n-dimensional irreducible components $X_i$ and to any closed subvariety $V \subseteq X$ you get a class

$$ cl_X(V):=i_*cl(V) \in H_{2k}(X)$$

where $i_*$ is push forward of "Borel-Moore homology" and $cl(V)\in H_{2k}(V)$.
This defines a map

$$cl(X): Z_k(X) \rightarrow H_{2k}(X)$$

by

$$cl(X)(\sum_i n_i[V_i]):= \sum n_i cl_X(V_i) \in H_{2k}(X).$$

In proposition 19.1.1 in the same book it is shown that if $\alpha \cong 0$ is rationally equivalent to zero it follows $cl(X)(\alpha)=0$, hence you get a well defined map

$$cl: A_k(X) \rightarrow H_{2k}(X)$$

for any such $H_*$

**Question:** "Even an example with say P1 would be helpful here. I know very little algebraic geometry overall (say only Hartshorne I and the first few chapters of II), so hopefully a minimal amount of reference to say divisors or intersection theory would be ideal (but I'm not sure if this is possible!)"

**Answer:** If $H_*$ is singular homology and if $X$ is any irreducible n-dimensional complex algebraic variety and $V \subseteq X$ a k-dimensional subvariety we may view $V,X$ as topological spaces in the strong topology and get a push forward map

$$i_*:H_*(V) \rightarrow H_*(X)$$

and since the "fundamental class" $[V]$ of $V$ generates $H_{2k}(V)$ there is a canonical element $i_*[V]\in H_{2k}(X)$ and this defines the cycle map $cl_X([V]):=i_*[V]$. In the case of $C:=\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ any divisor  $D:= \sum_i n_i[P_i]$ gives a formal sum where $P_i \in C$ is a closed point and you get an element $i_*[P_i] \in H_*(C)$. This gives rise to  the cycle map

$$cl_C: A_*(C)\rightarrow H_*(C).$$

The difficult part here is to prove that cycles that are rationally equivalent to zero maps to zero under $cl_C$. By the projective bundle formula it follows $A_*(C) \cong\mathbb{Z}[t]/(t^2)$.

If you use the singular chain complex $C_n(X)$ to define $H_n(X):=ker(d_n)/Im(d_{n+1})$, it should be possible to give an "elementary construction" and to prove that for any cycle $\alpha_k \in Z_k(X)$ rationally equivalent to zero, there is a topological cycle $z\in C_{2k+1}(X)$ with $d_{2k+1}(z)=i_*(\alpha_k)$, hence $cl_X(\alpha_k)=0$ in $H_{2k}(X)$. I believe this is possible and has been written down but I do not have a precise reference to the litterature.

Answer (score 0):

This is in Griffiths and Harris's principle of algebraic geometry page 61.

Suppose $M$ is a compact complex manifold of dimension $n$, $V\subset M$ is a subvariety of dimension $k$, given $\phi\in \mathcal{A}^{2k-1}(M)$, we have
$\int_V d\phi=0$. Hence, we can define a linear functional on $l:H^{2k}_{\text{dR}}(M)\mapsto \mathbb{C}$, $l([\phi])= \int_V\phi$. By Poincare duality for de Rham cohomology, we have $l$ as an element in $H^{2n-2k}_{\text{dR}}(M)$, called the fundamental class of $V$.

Note that we can integrate over $V$ although it's possibly singular. It's done on page 33 of G&H.