# Why should analytic classes sit inside $H^{p,p}(X)$ for various values of $p>0$?

Tags: complex-geometry, several-complex-variables, hodge-theory, algebraic-cycles

I am reading these notes [notes](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Empopa/571/chapter1.pdf) by Popa. I did some reading [of this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4236566/a-simple-interpretation-of-algebraic-cycles-as-homology-classes) but I didn't exactly answer my question.

It is claimed in example 4.5 that analytic classes sit inside $H^{p,p}(X)$ for various values of $p$. I do not know how to prove such a fact / nor do I see why it needs to be true.

Recall that an analytic class essentially is a cohomology class that comes from an algebraic subvariety of $X$ where $X$ is say a smooth complex manifold. If $V$ is a subvariety of codimension $p$, then $[V]\in H_{2n-2p}(X,\mathbb{C})$ is clear to me. By Poincare duality $[V]\in H^{2p}(X,\mathbb{C})$. Then I can apply the Hodge decomposition to get $[V]\in\bigoplus_{i+j=2p} H^{i,j}(X)$. However, I see no reason to have $[V]$ sitting precisely in $H^{p,p}(X)$.

What am I missing here / can someone provide a geometric picture to keep in mind?

Comment: Taking the cup-product with $[V] \in H^{2p}(X)$ means restricting $(2n-2p)$-forms to $V$ then integrating. But the restriction of an $(i,j)$-form (with $i+j=2n-2p$) to $V$ is nonzero only if $i=j=n-p$. So the only component of the Hodge decomposition that $[V]$ doesn’t annihilate is $H^{n-p,n-p}(X)$. This means $[V] \in H^{p,p}(X)$.

Comment: Can you complex why $V$ is nonzero only if $i=j=n-p$? Sorry I’m typing on my phone and it’s hard to read this.

Comment: I didn’t write iff, I wrote “only if”. The reason is that if (say) $i > \dim_{\mathbb{C}}\,V$, you can’t have an $(i,j)$-form on $V$, since you’d need (even locally) to take a wedge product of $i$ holomorphic coordinates – when the, say, “holomorphic cotangent space” has dimension $<i$.

Comment: Ah okay. The only way it can be possibly nonzero is if that condition holds. That makes more sense. Thanks! You can post this as answer if you’d like and I’ll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $i,j$ be integers such that $i+j=2n-2p$ and $i>n-p=\dim_{\mathbb{C}}\,V$. Let $\omega \in H^{i,j}(X)$. Then $[V] \wedge \omega \in H^{2n}$ is (up to a constant) $\int_{V}{\omega_{|V}}$. But locally, by definition, $\omega$ is a wedge product of $i$ local holomorphic coordinates and $j$-antiholomorphic ones, with $i> \dim_{\mathbb{C}}$. So said wedge product must vanish when restricted to $V$, thus $[V] \wedge \omega=0$.

In other words, cup-product with $[V]$ annihilates the $H^{i,j}(X)$ with $i+j=2n-2p$ and $i>n-p$. For a similar reason, cup-product with $[V]$ annihiates the $H^{i,j}(X)$ with $i+j=2n-2p$ and $j > n-p$.

Thus the projection of $[V]$ to any $H^{u,v}(X)$ with $u+v=2p$ and $(u,v) \neq (p,p)$ is zero, so $[V]\in H^{p,p}(X)$.